# Is there a good way of testing different timezones for your iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, timezone

I'm wondering if there are some tools out there that let you do iOS testing with different timezones to ensure that times are properly represented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was use the Simulator and change my location. In the iOS Simulator menu select Debug -> Location -> Custom Location. There you can set the latitude and longitude and test the display of date/time based on your simulated location.